# Extracting a file with ark

Tags: ark

When I try to extract the file and suggest a name  - no response - when I try to rename it I get a message -in italian - basically meaning this ... the file contains "voci con percorsi assoluti" - parametres - not supported by ark- is there any way of fixing this- adding info etc in such a way tht it  is able to open this file

Answer (score 0):

Settings > configure Ark > Untick "Preserve paths when extracting"

Comment: Hello  - Linux is very new to me - strugging to find out where the: settings-configure  Ark - section is. Where do I find this exactly? I understand where to find the console , accessories , graphics etc-from there where do I go?